# sp_send_dbmail appending (null) at the end of email body

Tags: sql-server, null, sp-send-dbmail

I am using SQL Server `sp_send_dbmail` to send email notifications (HTML body).
Here is my configuration.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail        
     @recipients = @list,
     @copy_recipients = @ccList,
     @importance = 'NORMAL',
     @subject = @subject,
     @body = @body,
     @body_format = N'html',
     @profile_name = 'myProfile'
```

Email is working as expected but I'm getting (null) at the end of the email body.

```
Thanks, 
Project Team.

(null)
```

I have also verified my HTML for invalid chars and image.

Comment: How do you get @body?

Comment: @body is a string content (appending HTML) and I have verified HTML, it is proper

Comment: add the`@body` definition to your question.  We need to see as much as possible.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more.

Comment: Html can be right, but null is in the text @body

Comment: This is the last line : `SET @body = @body + ' Thanks, <br/> Project Team.';`

Comment: 'EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail ..'  full text? present @query/@attach_query_result_as_file?

Comment: I am not using `@query/@attach_query_result_as_file`